# Computer freeze, about 1 sec, every now and then

Tags: windows-10, freeze, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-core-i7

I've had this problem for some time now, the computer/screen freezes every now and then for about 1-2 seconds and then works like normal. I haven't cared about it till' now that I started playing game that little freeze means death.

Usually but (I think) not always I hear fans go hard before/during the freeze, I assume it is the GPU fans.

Any recommendations how I can try to track down what is causing it and how to fix it?

If it matters the hardware is i7 and 1080.

Comment: One possibility:   Look for non-compliant 32-bit context extension Apps and replace with the the 64-bit counterparts.

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide more details such as exact hardware details and OS version.

Comment: run taskmgr  or get process Hacker or Sysinternals Procexp and sort by CPU, maybe lack of RAM?

Comment: Use temperature sensor products, such as CPU-Z and GPU-Z, to see if your computer is over-warming.